# Create ZipArchive of Excel XLSX file with EPPLUS C#

Tags: c#, excel, zip, archive, epplus

I have the folowing function to return a `FileStreamResult` for my ASP.NET MVC application.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a FileStreamResult containing a zip file with the EXCEL file in it
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
/// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the EXCEL file</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The file name of the EXCEL</param>
/// <returns>FileStreamResult</returns>
public FileStreamResult CreateZipFileFileStreamResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
{   
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    var contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip;

    ExcelPackage excelPackage = null;

    ZipArchive archive = null;

    try
    {
        excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(ms);

        var workSheet1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);

        excelPackage.SaveAs(ms);



        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        archive = new ZipArchive(excelPackage.Stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

        var newEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest);

        var newEntryStream = newEntry.Open();

        var fsr = new FileStreamResult(excelPackage.Stream, contentType);
        fsr.FileDownloadName = fileName + ".zip";

        return fsr;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (archive != null)
            archive.Dispose();

        if (excelPackage != null)
            excelPackage.Dispose();

        if (ms != null)
            ms.Dispose();

        throw;
    }
}
```

The function returns something, but is is in a split XML fashion rather that one XLSX file.

I want it to a return a ZIPPED single file.

This is what the current result looks like.

[image: ZIP archive structure]

Having used the help given by @kuujinbo I have created this function.
Please note that for some reason FileContentResult works and FileStreamResult does not work.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a FileStreamResult containing a zip file with the EXCEL file in it
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
        /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the EXCEL file</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the EXCEL</param>
        /// <returns>FileStreamResult</returns>        
        public FileContentResult CreateZipFileFileContentResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
        {
            var contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip;

            using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
                {
                    using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                    {
                        var workSheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                        workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);

                        var firstRow = workSheet1.Row(1);
                        if (firstRow != null)
                            firstRow.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                        zip.AddEntry(fileName, package.GetAsByteArray());
                        zip.Save(memoryStream);
                        var fcr = new FileContentResult(memoryStream.ToArray(), contentType); //NOTE: Using a File Stream Result will not work.
                        fcr.FileDownloadName = fileName + ".zip";
                        return fcr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: looks like that's what it is supposed to be. xlsx files are zipped opendocument structures. I think your file explorer is just showing the ZIP content transparently in the directory hierarchy (given the icon in the top left corner). when you rename .zip to .xlsx you will be able to open it with Excel.

Comment: + you never write anything to `newEntryStream`? This function seems to just returns the EPPlus output stream (which already is a ZIP internally and supposed to have xlsx extension) with a .zip extension.

Comment: It sems you are correct. I will take a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since EPPlus *internally* uses a version of [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) , (take a look at the source code) try and do the same. IMHO their design decision tells a lot about why some choose **not** to use [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
class TestObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<TestObject> objectList = new List<TestObject>()
{
    { new TestObject() {Id = 0, Name = "zero" } },
    { new TestObject() {Id = 1, Name = "one" } }
};
string ExcelName = "test.xlsx";
string ZipName = "test.zip"; 

public ActionResult DotnetZip()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<TestObject>(objectList, true);
                zip.AddEntry(ExcelName, package.GetAsByteArray());
                zip.Save(stream);
                return File(
                    stream.ToArray(),
                    System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip,
                    ZipName
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and working:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to get a ZIP file not an EXCEL fille. I already know how to get the EXCEL file. :)

Comment: @DragosDurlut - sorry, my bad. Updated the answer with a working solution.

Comment: do they use a modified (faster) compression? or how could a second pass gain another ~20% packing?

Comment: @kuujinbo No problem. I will test and I will mark as answer as that is the case. Thank you! +1 from me!

Comment: @kuujinbo Aparently the problem is with the return file type.
FileContentResult  works, FileStreamResult does not work...

Comment: @DragosDurlut - according to the release note from 4.0.5 version: '_Replaced Packaging API with DotNetZip
This will remove any problems with Isolated Storage and enable multi threading_'.

Comment: @DragosDurlut - just trying to answer your earlier comment about why `EPPlus` uses `DotNetZip` instead of the BCL compression/archive classes.